# sed: bad option in substitution expression : bad option in substitution expression

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string like this

```
string="10.212.1.1/29"
```

and when I use `sed` command like this I am getting error of  `bad option` which is most probably due to `/29`  **/** is this . How I can fix this as I want to replace this part

my command is like this

```
sed -i "s/variable \"vpc\".*/variable \"vpc\" { default = \"$string\" }/g"  var.tf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a different sed separator:

```
sed -i "s#variable \"vpc\".*#variable \"vpc\" { default = \"$string\" }#g"  var.tf
```